# QueryDsl - filtering Map based on key

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, dictionary, querydsl

I have folowing property in my hibenrate entity class:

```
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "language_code")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "text_translations", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "text_id"))
private Map<Language, String> translations = new HashMap<>();
```

Now I want to query this entity and filter content of map by user's language (i.e. by map's key). I have folowing join in my query:

```
StringPath titleTran = new StringPath("title_tran");
from(entity).
.leftJoin(entity.translations, titleTran).fetch().where(?mapKey?.eq(userLanguage));
```

What I need is ?mapKey? to by path to language of titleTran path. Is this somehow possible in QueryDsl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to search for a given Map key, you can use the following HQL query:

```
select me
from MyEntity me
join me.translations tr
where
    index(tr) = :lang
```

or with JPQL:

```
select me
from MyEntity me
join me.translations tr
where
    key(tr) = :lang
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution. Actually I also found a KEY directive that seems to by made for maps. Anyway, those directives are not implemented in QueryDsl (or I was not able to find them in doc?).

Answer (score 0):

In Querydsl JPA the following works

```
query.from(me).where(me.translations.containsKey(lang)).list(me);
```

Comment: This will just filter out all entities that dont have specific translation. I wanted to fetch entities together with specific translation. Actually i want fallback translation if specific is not found, but that is another problem that I currently solve by subquery that does the same thing as containsKey (probably not very effective).